# Build process template always empty - VS2012 & MS TFS repository

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

I'm trying to define a new build on TFS using VS2012. When I go to New Build Definition -> Processes I'm seeing "Build process template" and an empty drop down.

I click on the "New..." button selects the default template from

```
$/<My Project Name>/BuildProcessTemplates/DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml
```

and click OK but then I'm getting the error:

```
TF277000: A build process template for '$/<My Project Name>/BuildProcessTemplates/DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml' already exists for team project <Project Name>. You cannot create another build process template for the same file. Use the existing one instead.
```

the drop down always stay empty. I tried to clean cache(AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0) and other sort brilliant tricks like close and open but nothing helped - the drop down stays empty.

[image: VS2012 new Build screens]

I would really appreciate aמy help.

Comment: Just curious - have you found any solution to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue crop up recently.

*Background:* TFS 2012 Project with multiple solutions under 1 Project Collection project. The 'BuildProcessTemplates' folder did exist in the Project collection project and did contain the standard templates.  The solution was created in TFS 2012 and being coded using VS 2012 ultimate.

*Symptoms:* Any attempts to create a Build Definition failed due to a lack of Templates.

*Actions - unsuccessful:* I created a copy of the default template and used that for a template. I wasn't able to create a Build Definition since even with that, the dropdown was still empty. Also tried creating a custom template with the same lack of success.

*Actions - successful:* I separated the solutions into their own Project Collections projects.  That put the solution at the same level as the 'BuildProcessTemplates' folder. Once that was accomplished, I was able to create a Build Definition for those solutions.

*Comments:* I'm not sure if this is a bug in TFS 2012 or not. I would like to think if it is a bug in TFS 2012, it is corrected in TFS 2013.

Your thoughts?

Robert

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem with not being able to see build process templates when trying to add a new build definition.  We are in TFS 2012.  This team project also appeared not to have any build definitions.  That was expected though because we had not yet used the TFS builds on this team project.

The problem was caused by someone with admin rights setting the "View build definition" and the "View Builds" access rights to Deny for everyone.

By just setting that back to allow on the TFS group, we suddenly could see the build definitions and also were able to select build process templates.

It was really strange that it let us add new build process templates, but we couldn't select them.