# Visual Studio 2012 Build Process Template Dropdown does not populate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build-server

My issue is that I cannot select a build process template after migrating to TFS/VS2012.
I managed to google and find one article which suggest the same problem here,
[Possible Bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bb4cfef-f239-4841-8656-761f6ef41c3b/possible-bug-tfs-2012-build-process-template)

Any ideas how I can get the dropdown to load the Build Process Templates or why they may not be getting loaded?

Also, I am able to click New->Copy Template, and copy successfully, but it never populates the dropdown list after accepting.

[Possibly the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253080/build-process-template-alwatys-empty-vs2012-ms-tfs-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem but not related to upgrading the server.  We were not able to see build process templates when trying to add a new build definition.  We are in TFS 2012.  This team project also appeared not to have any build definitions.  That was expected though because we had not yet used the TFS builds on this team project.

The problem was caused by someone with admin rights setting the "View build definition" and the "View Builds" access rights to Deny for everyone.

By just setting that back to allow on the TFS group, we suddenly could see the build definitions and also were able to select build process templates.

It was really strange that it let us add new build process templates, but we couldn't select them.

Comment: Yes, seems the issue can be caused by a number of problems. Hope the comments/answers here help others. I will tag this as correct since I have no vote power ;/ and let SE users decide which is more common.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. Same user in two different groups having conflicting permission settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo...

I was finally able to get the templates loading by doing the following.

1. Unmapped the entire TFS project which had been mapped in a sub folder and not at the root.
2. Deleted files from disk completely
3. Remapped the TFS project, this time from the root TFS project level
4. Accepted the "get"

After doing this my build definitions loaded and worked. (Seems to be a mapping issue...bug...)

This may be an extream solution and I am still not sure what happened but it now works.